# Validating Form

Tags: jquery, validation, submit

How to validate form fields on submit button using jquery?

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery.validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin is the best solution I've found.

All you have to do is give the inputs the class "required" and then call .validate() on the form in your document.ready call e.g.

```
$(function() { 
    $('#idofyourform').validate();
});
```

You can also do email and other types of validation using the same method. The plugin is also extensible for your own rules.

Remember you will also need to validate any data server side.

**Edit: Response to comment**

To validate only when the form is submitted add the following option:

```
$("#idofyourform").validate({
   onsubmit: true,
   onkeyup: false,
   onfocusout: false,
   onclick: false
})
```

Have a read of [the options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for more detail.

Comment: I know that one ..but how do I use that to validate only when form is submitted.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want inline validation? Only when the user clicks submit? If so see expanded answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry I've misremembered this. It's the other way around. I've editted my code to reflect this.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error ..here is my code
$('#formname').validate({onsubmit:true,onkeyup:false,onclick:false});

Comment: You haven't got onfocusout:false is it still validating when you leave a textbox?

Comment: I added that too. It doesn't validate in any way. Do you have a working example?

Comment: You do have the class "required" or "email" on the fields?

Comment: Yes, I do have class "required" on the fields